# Is there a combination of “LIKE” and “IN” in athena?

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I'm looking for a way to "like" and "in"
I've tries the sql way and I get this error

```
Error running query: SYNTAX_ERROR: line 4:5: Unexpected parameters (varchar, varchar(35)) for function contains. Expected: contains(array(T), T) T:comparable
```

This is the line I use

```
WHERE CONTAINS(name, 'registration_time% or login_failed%')
```

After reading a bit about contains it seems like its use in athena is completely different so is there any other way to do something like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use *regexp_like*

```
SELECT regexp_like('login_failed xxx', '(registration_time|login_failed)')
```

or in WHERE

```
WHERE regexp_like(name, '(registration_time|login_failed)')
```